# Watch directory for new files with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, filesystems

I have a function called *loadDATA* that loads the file *data.json* from the server in the same directory where the js file is.  I now need to watch that directory for new a new .json file that will appear every 5 minutes, grab the name and replace the initial data.json URL that is passed to the new .json filename which I will not know unfortunately.

I've been looking at js to do this but keep seeing php responses.  Is it possible with js and just a pain in the ars.  I'm not against using php, it's just been awhile and if I remember a little more intuitive.  I did see something called node.js but it's not clear to me if it is compatible with IE as well.  I open to all suggestions on approaching this.  Thank you for the help.

```
    jsonURL = "data.json";

    function loadDATA() {
      $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json) {
//Do some stuff

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess hypothetically you could ask for the index of the directory, and if it doesn't exist then the server should return a list of files in there, possibly even with their modification times. So that would make it possible.

On the other hand, PHP would make it so much easier.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to look into php, just unsure right now how to pass the php variable name to javascript which is just a google away :)

Comment: It's easy enough for PHP to just be `echo implode("\n",glob("*"));`, then have JS do `response.split("\n")` and there you have the list of filenames. If you want the modification times too, try `<?php foreach(glob("*") as $f) echo $f."/".filemtime($f)."\n"; ?>` and the JS is still `response.split("\n")`, but for each filename do an additional `split("/")`. The second one is the modification time, which you need to multiply by 1000 to get the same timestamp in JS (since JS uses milliseconds)